# Protecting XPages (hiding custom controls source code)

Tags: xpages

I am trying to protect my XPages custom controls (hide `*.xsp` source files) using Stephan H. Wissel's arcticle "[Protecting your XPages Application](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99W7MJ)", but I had no luck.

I have a single `*.xsp` which contains a custom control.
When I have made all the instuctions, I tried to open my page and I got an error

> 404:  HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception.

If I remove the custom control from the page it will work.

Have somebody been successful using this technique?
I appriciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Smells like compiler errors. What does the log say?